# Google Fusion Tables Map filtered by a selection list in JS

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to create a website that filters data from a Fusion table onto a google map using a select list.  I can't find the correct way to pass a variable through a JS query (or at least just the dropdown list value.)  Can anyone help?
Here is my current code...I would want the place, schools and price variables to be in WHERE clauses.  So I want to replace the word AVON with the value of the select list.

```
  <script>
    var map;

    function initialize() {
      var indy = new google.maps.LatLng(39.788945, -86.149937);
      var place = document.getElementById("citydrop").value;
      var schools = document.getElementById("schooldrop").value;
      var price = document.getElementById("pricedrop").value;
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: indy,
        zoom: 10
      });

      var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: 'Address',
          from: '1DsfPFeKrW2pegZhfSRJmLqYrlJc0HLF3nZcK4kQ',
          where: "'CITY' = AVON"
        }
      });
      layer.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Another note: citydrop, schooldrop and pricedrop are the ID's for select lists.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issue here. Your var place, var schools, var price need to be globals, i.e.outside your initialize(){ ... } function. Put them under where  var map; is.  Just the var price, etc. You can leave the setting of them where they are.

Replace:

```
where: "'CITY' = AVON"
```

With:

```
where: "'CITY' = 'AVON' AND 'SCHOOLS' = '" + schools + "' AND 'PRICE' = '" + price + '";
```

Do you have more than 1 school? The syntax might change if so.  Get it working with 1 first then ask how to handle multiple schools.  I think it's CONTAINS.

Comment: The syntax for multiple items is IN ('item1', 'item2'). On a separate note you might want to take a look at Derek Eder's Searchable Map Template which provides this kind of functionality:
http://derekeder.com/searchable_map_template/

Comment: If you have multiple schools, you might hit the "request uri too large" issue. Keep in mind.